# Что не так с grid?

Tags: css, grid

Почему-то образуется пустая ячейка под .first-product-card не могу понять, что мешает.

Подскажите, что делаю не так с grid?

https://jsfiddle.net/Nikita_Migushev/41z506m2/1/

```css
@supports (grid-area: auto) {
  .inner-wrap {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1em;
  }

.page-wrap {
  width: 120em;
}

    .inner-wrap {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 385px);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 200px);
    }

    #firstCard {
      grid-column: 1/2;
      grid-row: 1/3;
    }

    #secondCard {
      grid-column: 2/3;
      grid-row: 1/2;
    }

    #thirdCard {
      grid-column: 3/4;
      grid-row: 1/2;
    }

    #fourthCard {
      grid-column: 2/3;
      grid-row: 2/3;
    }

    #fifthCard {
      grid-column: 3/4;
      grid-row: 2/3;
}

    }
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ) Там проблема была в том, что на ячеку под .first-product-card распространилась ссылка . Убрал, и все встало на свои места. https://jsfiddle.net/Nikita_Migushev/41z506m2/3/

```
<div class="lower-border-line"></div>
      <div class="product-properties">
        <ul>
          <li><small>Free shipping</small></li>
          <li><small>New</small></li>
          <li><small>00:02:29</small></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```